# How do I push my git repository to dokku?

Tags: git, github, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm new to Dokku, where I am using it in conjunction with a DigitalOcean droplet.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/application-deployment/).

My problem is that when I go to push my git repository from Github to dokku, I receive this message:

```
.git > git push -vvv dokku master
Pushing to dokku@dokku.me:my-rails-app
ssh: connect to host dokku.me port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked to see if I was connected with Github and I seem to be:

```
my-rails-app > ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Hi xxxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I know the repository exists. Any idea why this push times out? What rights might I be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The push dokku master will push to hte remote doku, the one you have added with

```
git remote add dokku dokku@dokku.me:ruby-rails-sample
```

So the fact that you are or are not connected to GitHub is not relevant.

You need to make sure `ssh -T dokku.me` is working.
That supposes of course you have replaced dokku.me by the name of your actual dokku server, as seen in this [dokku user management documentation comment](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku~v0.6.2/deployment/user-management/#adding-deploy-users).

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate it.